# How to secure toilet fill valve hose to canister

Tags: plumbing, toilet, plumbing-fixture

I have a Kohler Wellworth (low flow model) that uses a canister-style flushing mechanism. The tube that comes from the fill valve is to be seated/secured in an opening at the top of the canister, held in place by what I assume should be a snug fit. However, the hose continually pops out of place after flushing.
Is it safe & effective to glue a hose like this in place? I can't see a place that a typical clip could be used to hold it in position.

Comment: For now I have a zip tie shoved in at one end to make the tube fit tighter & rapped around the top end. I also wrapped silver tape around it after. I need the get electical tape. Stores have tried to sell me things that do not fit. I had to cone up with my own fix...but if someone knows where I can get a hose clamp I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about something like this:

[image: https://www.plumbingsupply.com/images/kohler-canister-flush-valve-1070282.jpg]
<sup>Source: plumbingsupply.com</sup>

and that the tube is connected to the protrusion at the top, I would suggest a simple hose clamp to hold it in place.

[image: https://www.hcl-clamping.com/cw4/images/product_full/l-worm-saej1670.jpg]
<sup>Source: hcl-clamping.com</sup>

They come in a wide variety of sizes and one small enough to fit that would be pretty cheap. Just don't over tighten and crush the input fitting.

A zip tie might work, as well, and they are as cheap as can be, and when you're using one small enough for that fitting, it's hard to pull on it hard enough to do damage.

If the larger portion of the fitting is still in place, push the tubing on far enough to reach the top of the canister itself and a very small amount of pressure around the smaller diameter portion (from either the zip-tie or the hose clamp) will be enough to squeeze the tube so that it can't slip up over the larger diameter.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! That's also the exact canister I ordered to replace this one (though I needed the ~1.28gpf model instead).

Answer (score 1):

- Try one wrap of electrical tape around the tube. If that ever fails, move on to hot glue (or try two wraps).
- Try nipping a 1/4" or so off the tube, if there's enough slack.
- Try detaching the tube and reversing it.

Answer (score 1):

No need for zip tie or hose clamp. Instead wrap a twist tie around tightly and twist the ends to secure. If there's room, add a second one for extra security.

Answer (score 0):

A clip or clamp on the hose will do nothing to keeping the hose "up in" a cavity. A pressure fitting is needed, that expands into the cavity.  Check with the plumbing expert where you purchased the device.

Use an appropriate length braided stainless steel covering hose. If you must use adapters, stainless is best.

No bi-metal interactions that way. Else brass is the least reactive.

Comment: I believe you’re misunderstanding what type of hose the original question was in regards to. I was asking about the small rubber hose INSIDE the tank, which connects the fill valve to the canister (both made of plastic).